# Javascript: how can global functions use data dynamically obtained from readFileData

Tags: javascript

I have the following code (simplified from a more elaborate code):

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input id="newfile" accept='text/plain' type="file" onchange="readFileData(event)" />
</form>
...
<p id="description"></p>
```

Javascript

```
var setname = '';
function readFileData(event) {
  file = event.target.files[0];
  setname = file.name.split('.')[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    dictionary = toDict(e.target.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
desc = document.getElementById('description');

desc.innerHTML = setname
function useDictionary(dictionary) {
  // more code here
}
```

Notes:

1. the function `useDictionary()` is going to be used by another HTML element's `onkeyup` function, so maybe it has to be accessible from the global level, I'm not so sure.
2. the files being accessed are only local in relation to the html file, and this is a single html file.
3. I am using vanilla javascript, no preprocessors or libraries, and I want to keep it that way.

My main questions, however, are these. How can I make `desc.innerHTML` access the variable `setname`? How can I make the function `useDictionary()` access the variable `dictionary`?

I have tried inserting `useDictionary()` within the `reader.onload` block, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create objects with methods which would manage the global state and / or the HTML representation, like:

```
const stateManager = (function(){
   let _dictionary = null;
   return {
      setValue: function( value ){ _dictionary = value },
      getValue: function(){ return _dictionary; },
      ...
   }
})();
```

```
const viewManager = (function(){
   let _target = null;
   return {
      init: function(){
          _target = document.getElementById('description');
      },
      update: function( value ){
          if( _target ){
            _target.innerHTML = value;
          }
      },
      ...
   }
})();
```

This way you could set and get all the values in a convenient way from anywhere.
You can (and probably should) also handle some validation and error handling, independent from other code.

E.g. some code like `onClick()` can just call `.setValue(...)` or `.getValue()`, and be sure to receive or set the correct value, or a properly handled fallback state.

Comment: I've made several permutations of the code to somehow conform with your suggestions, but perhaps I am just too unfamiliar regarding states and representation, that I couldn't get around to solve the problem. Perhaps a more specific instruction would help?

Comment: You need to call `viewManager.init()` when the DOM is loaded, e.g. `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { viewManager.init(); });`. Then you should be able to access `stateManager` and `viewManager` from anywhere, like `stateManager.setValue( toDict(e.target.result) );` and `viewManager.update( fileName );`.